# Order a list based on another list Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two list `list1` and `list2` like below

| List 1 | List 2 |
| --- | --- |
| {"EmpName":"Tony","EmpId":123} | {"EmpName":"David","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"Mark","EmpId":123} | {"EmpName":"Steve","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"Steve","EmpId":123} | {"EmpName":"Mark","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"David","EmpId":123} |  |
| {"EmpName":"John","EmpId":123} |  |
| {"EmpName":"Jim","EmpId":123} |  |

Now I wanted to sort list1 based on list2.

Elements in `list1` if not on `list2` would be on the top, and if the element is present in `list2` then it should be in the same order as `list2` .

So I'm expecting the result table to be like this.

| Result list |
| --- |
| {"EmpName":"Tony","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"John","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"Jim","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"David","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"Steve","EmpId":123} |
| {"EmpName":"Mark","EmpId":123} |

I have the below code to do this, and it works. I'm really not sure whether this would break during some case or if there is any better way to achieve this:

```java
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Employee("Tony",123));
list.add(new Employee("Mark",123));
list.add(new Employee("Steve",123));
list.add(new Employee("David",123));
list.add(new Employee("John",123));
list.add(new Employee("Jim",123));

List<Person> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(new Employee("David",123));
list2.add(new Employee("Steve",123));
list2.add(new Employee("Mark",123));

List<Person> newList = new ArrayList<>();
list2.forEach(e->{
        if(list.stream().filter(doc->e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(doc.getName())).findAny().isPresent()){
                newList.add(e);
                list.removeIf(i->i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getName()));
            }
        });
        list.addAll(newList);
        System.out.println(list);

    }
```

Comment: which keyword in your code, is to **sort**?

Comment: @LeiYang What you mean?

Comment: Are you matching lists by the `name` property only? Not by the int property?

Comment: i mean, you mentioned **sort**, and 'below code to do this, and it works', but i wonder whether your code really sort something?

Comment: @ernest_k Yes I'm sorting only by `name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a map with indexes of each name, to simplify the lookup:

```
Map<String, Integer> indexOfMap = IntStream.range(0, list2.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(list2.get(i).getName(), i))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Then implement a `Comparator` that sorts by looking up names in `indexOfMap`:

```
Comparator<Employee> comparator = (a, b) -> 
   indexOfMap.containsKey(a.getName()) && indexOfMap.containsKey(b.getName())
        ? indexOfMap.get(a.getName()) - indexOfMap.get(b.getName())
        : (!indexOfMap.containsKey(a.getName()) ? -1 : 1);

//you can make a copy of list if you don't want to change it
//or you can stick to your stream and just use sorted with the comparator
list.sort(comparator);
```

Note that the order of the first elements in the resulting list is not deterministic (because it's just all elements not present in `list2`, with no further ordering). All of the values at the end of the list will be in their order dictated by the `list2`.

Answer (score 2):

Note : Having an `equals` and `hashCode` for `Employee` is required so that `list::contains` would work.

First find all the elements in list1 that are not in list2.

```java
list3 = list1.stream()
             .filter(Predicate.not(list2::contains))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then, if

1. There are no elements in list2 which are **NOT** part of `list1`. In this case, just simply add all elements of list2 to list1

```java
list3.addAll(list2);
```

2. There are elements in list2 which may/may not be in list1. Add elements from list2 which are in list1 to list3.

```java
list3.addAll(list2.stream().filter(list1::contains).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Tip for the reader: Defining your `Employee` class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) (new feature in Java 16) lets the compiler implicitly create the needed `equals` & `hashCode` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new list. see the below code it is simple 2 step process

```
 list2.stream().forEach((e)->list.removeIf(employee->employee.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getName())));
        
        list.addAll(list2);

list.stream().forEach((employee)->{
            System.out.println(employee.getName());
        });
```

Comment: @user:6389865 This apporach would end up adding all the list 2 to list 1. What if `list` dont have `Steve` but `list2` has.

Comment: Did you check the comment